# How to limit the number of feed status returned by the Facebook PowerShell Module

Tags: facebook, powershell

I'm using  [`Facebook PowerShell Module`](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com/) to interact with my `Facebook` account using `PowerShell`.

To list the feed of the specified user, I use the cmdlet `Get-FBFeed`, the problem is that, this cmdlet alone returns a big number of status updates, how can I do to return just like the 10 or 15 last status updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function doesn't contain a limit\last parameter, so you would need to extract it yourself. I haven't used the module, but you need to:

1. Find a property with the date and time(you might need to cast to `[datetime]` if it's stored as a string)
2. Sort by the date property desecending
3. Get first 10, 15 etc..

Codesample:

```
Get-FBFeed |
Sort-Object -Descending Date |#You need to change Date to the right property, and maybe cast the value to datetime
Select-Object -First 10
```